# The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context after swapping server from local to external

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity-2

I have this error after transfer my whole data from local to external server. Both databases have same tables etc. How to fix this? It was work correctly before change server from local to external. Data that are different from register or login are adding correctly.

Connecton string

```
<add name="DefaultConnectionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.BiuroModel.csdl|res://*/Models.BiuroModel.ssdl|
     res://*/Models.BiuroModel.msl;
     provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
     provider connection string=&quot;
     Data Source=db-mssql;Initial Catalog=inzS9776;
     Persist Security Info=True;User ID=inzS9776;
     Password=xxxxx&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

DefaultConnectionEntities class

```
public partial class DefaultConnectionEntities : DbContext
{
    public DefaultConnectionEntities()
        : base("DefaultConnectionEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<C__MigrationHistory> C__MigrationHistory { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Hotel> Hotel { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Klient> Klient { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Oferta> Oferta { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Opinia> Opinia { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Osoba> Osoba { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Pensjonat> Pensjonat { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Pracownik> Pracownik { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Pracownik_biurowy> Pracownik_biurowy { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Przewodnik> Przewodnik { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Region> Region { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Transport> Transport { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Ubezpieczenia> Ubezpieczenia { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Wybrana_wycieczka> Wybrana_wycieczka { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<WybraneUbezpieczenie> WybraneUbezpieczenie { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Wycieczka_fakultatywna> Wycieczka_fakultatywna { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Zakwaterowanie> Zakwaterowanie { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Zamowienie> Zamowienie { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ZlozoneZamowienie> ZlozoneZamowienie { get; set; }
}
```

Application user:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Application Dbcontext:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnectionEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Account controller:

```
  public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private DefaultConnectionEntities db = new DefaultConnectionEntities();
    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }...................
```

Comment: Why are you using two different contexts? You can use one context that inherits from  `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`, And once do, remove the dbsets `DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles` , `DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers` and the rest of AspNet dbsets properties. What is the error you are getting?